# How to use order by clause with 2 fields with DESC in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want toppers but it may happen that more than one user have same score which is a highest score so amongst them I want to select one who has 1st reached to that score so I used following query but it is not giving me correct result.
I am using ruby on rails technology.

```
top_score_cards=Score.order("updated_at DESC,points DESC").uniq
```

Comment: `top_score_cards=Score.order("updated_at DESC").order("points DESC").uniq`

Comment: Thanks but it is also not giving the desired result

Comment: When you say "i want toppers" can you explain some more about what you mean?  Your question could use some better grammar and punctuation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your order by arguments need to be in the opposite order:  as it stands you will order by updated at first, and if there is a "tie" for updated at, you'll get the one with the highest score.  It needs to be the other way round.

Also, if you want the people who got that score first, you need to order by "updated_at ASC", since this will return the lowest time first.  You can just say "updated_at" since "ASC" is the default.

For example you could get the highest score, (the earliest if there is a tie for high score), with

```
top_score = Score.order("points DESC, updated_at").first
```

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do with the uniq, and you don't explain your requirements very well, but hopefully this will move you further forward.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I want top 3 highest marks gainer so my solution is :

```
@top_score_cards = Score.order("points DESC, updated_at").where("points != ? And activity_id= ? ",0,params[:@myActivity]).limit(3)
```